# How to keep content from scrolling over fixed background container?

Tags: html, css, scroll

I would like to have an image at the top which does not scroll. So I set the container of class `fixedbg` to `position: fixed`.

But then I want some content below that image, which does scroll but which should *hit a wall* when content reaches the bottom of the top container (`fixedbg`).

How does one do that using CSS?

In the current situation the content of the `scrollarea` container just flows over the `fixedbg`.

```css
.fixedbg {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: whitesmoke;
}

.scrollarea {
  top: 200px;
  position: relative;
  height: 800px;
}
```

```html
<div class="fixedbg"></div>
<div class="scrollarea">
  <p>scrollarea</p>
  <p>scrollarea</p>
  <p>scrollarea</p>
  <p>scrollarea</p>
  <p>scrollarea</p>
  <p>scrollarea</p>
  <p>scrollarea</p>
  <p>scrollarea</p>
  <p>scrollarea</p>
  <p>scrollarea</p>
</div>
```

Comment: `hit a wall` you mean stop the scroll ?

Comment: @Temani Afif Yes. I want the top of the content of the 'scrollarea' container to stop at the bottom of the 'fixedbg' container. So like 'hitting a wall' yes.

Comment: did you try inspecting the code. it has already hit the wall. the scroll area is immediately after fixedbg

Comment: Something like this? --> https://jsfiddle.net/7Lm5fu37/

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError No, in that fiddle the content still goes over the 'fixedbg'. I need the top image to stay fixed and the scrollarea text to stop under the bottom of the 'fixedbg' container.

Comment: @Wieger i think there is no CSS for what you need. By the way can you check my answer to see if it's what you need or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is no CSS solution. You may use jQuery and force a scroll back when you reach a certain limit. Here is an example :

```js
$(document).scroll(function(e) {
  if (($(".scrollarea").position().top - $(this).scrollTop() < 140)) {
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $(".scrollarea").offset().top-120
    }, 200);
  }
});
```

```css
body,html {
margin:0;
padding:0;
}

.fixedbg {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  background-image: url(https://lorempixel.com/400/200/);
  z-index:9;
}

.scrollarea {
  top: 200px;
  position: relative;
  height: 800px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="fixedbg"></div>
<div class="scrollarea">
  <p>scrollarea</p>
  <p>scrollarea</p>
  <p>scrollarea</p>
  <p>scrollarea</p>
  <p>scrollarea</p>
  <p>scrollarea</p>
  <p>scrollarea</p>
  <p>scrollarea</p>
  <p>scrollarea</p>
  <p>scrollarea</p>
</div>
```

Comment: If I grab the scrollbar I can still scroll the content under the top image. So this example doesn't quite work. Disabling or countering scroll using scripts is very tricky (in my opinion).

Comment: @Wieger i know that `it doesn't quite work`. I was wondering if this is what you expect, i mean is this the idea ? if yes i don't think there is something in CSS to block content from moving

Comment: I think I have to agree and accept that there is no CSS solution. I think I'm just going to scroll the background container together with the content underneath. Also, I'm going to accept your answer.

Answer (score -1):

Just add z-index in your fixed image css, then the content scroll from beneath the image. Check snippet.

```css
.fixedbg {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: whitesmoke;
}

.scrollarea {
  top: 200px;
  position: relative;
  height: 800px;
}
```

```html
<div class="fixedbg"></div>
<div class="scrollarea">
  <p>scrollarea</p>
  <p>scrollarea</p>
  <p>scrollarea</p>
  <p>scrollarea</p>
  <p>scrollarea</p>
  <p>scrollarea</p>
  <p>scrollarea</p>
  <p>scrollarea</p>
  <p>scrollarea</p>
  <p>scrollarea</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I would like it to not scroll over or under it. Just stop the content from scrolling under or over the container. Like hitting a wall.

Comment: basically what you want, when content hits bottom of container then content stop scrolling. So, for this you need to use jquery, it can't be possible with css.

Comment: Yes, using CSS. Or maybe something that gives the same 'effect' of hitting that wall. For instance, I've tried using a (transparent) 'filler' at the top of the 'scrollarea' container but then I would need to know or calculate the height of that filler, which varies.

Answer (score -2):

```css
.fixedbg {
   
}

.scrollarea {
  

position: fixed;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="fixedbg"></div>
<div class="scrollarea">
  <p>scrollarea</p>
  <p>scrollarea</p>
  <p>scrollarea</p>
  <p>scrollarea</p>
  <p>scrollarea</p>
  <p>scrollarea</p>
  <p>scrollarea</p>
  <p>scrollarea</p>
  <p>scrollarea</p>
  <p>scrollarea</p>
</div>
```

Comment: You should refrain from rude reactionary responses such as these Pratik, It should not be tolerated on StackOverflow.